# Need youtube audio to continue to play when iOS app enters background

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, youtube

My app has a UIWebView that plays specific youtube content within the app. Some of these videos can be lengthy and are more audio centric (e.g. lectures and/or music). I'd like users of the app to be able to leave the app but have the audio of the youtube video continue to play, without the need for hitting a resume or play button. How can this be done? I'm willing to abandon the UIWebView if there is a better alternative.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I work on the same troube. The problem come from the mpmovieplayer which play the movie in ios.

An article of Matt Gallagher said:
"This pause is sent from the CALayer displaying the video frames. This is a private class for an MPMoviePlayerController and is your own AVPlayerLayer for an AVPlayer."
source - http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2011/04/background-audio-through-ios-movie.html

This article is very old (2011), but maybe the problem is similar.

Good luck